# How to check if an hour exists in a specific Time Zone in .NET

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

During a Daylight Saving Time transition, the clock is moved forward, and so a specific hour will not exist in that specific day for that specific time zone.

Is there an easy way in .NET to find out if an hour exists or not for a time zone?

The only way I found was by trying to convert an hour to UTC, and check for an exception:

```
public bool IsValidTime(DateTime date, TimeZoneInfo tzi)
    {
        try
        {
            date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, tzi);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And so running something like this will return false:

```
  var date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 8);
  var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Cuba Standard Time");

  var isValid = IsValidTime(date, tzi);
```

Is there any built in way of doing this, that is less messy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IsInvalidTime` method of `TimeZoneInfo`.

From Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime?view=netframework-4.6.2

Example: In the Pacific Time zone, daylight saving time begins at 2:00 A.M. on April 2, 2006. The following code passes the time at one-minute intervals from 1:59 A.M. on April 2, 2006, to 3:01 A.M. on April 2, 2006, to the IsInvalidTime method of a TimeZoneInfo object that represents the Pacific Time zone. The console output indicates that all times from 2:00 A.M. on April 2, 2006, to 2:59 A.M. on April 2, 2006, are invalid.

```
// Specify DateTimeKind in Date constructor
DateTime baseTime = new DateTime(2007, 3, 11, 1, 59, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
DateTime newTime;

// Get Pacific Standard Time zone
TimeZoneInfo pstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

// List possible invalid times for a 63-minute interval, from 1:59 AM to 3:01 AM
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 63; ctr++)
{
   // Because of assignment, newTime.Kind is also DateTimeKind.Unspecified
   newTime = baseTime.AddMinutes(ctr);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is invalid: {1}", newTime, pstZone.IsInvalidTime(newTime));
}
```